# expected number of rolls to see all 6 dice faces GIVEN we have already seen 4 distinct faces

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Question: given that we have already seen 4 distinct faces of the dice so far, what is the expected number of rolls of the dice required until we see all 6? (The dice is fair.)

EDIT: The question is meant to indicate that we have seen EXACTLY 4 distinct faces so far.

I tried to model my solution in terms of the coupon collector problem/approach. Let $T$ be the number of rolls required until we see all $6$ faces. Let $F$ be the number of faces seen so far. Let $T_i$ be the number of rolls required to get the next new face given that we have already seen $4 + (i - 1) = 3 + i$ faces so far. Then $T_i - Geom((6 - (3 + i))/6) = Geom((3 - i) / 6)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 2$. Then $E(T | F = 4) = E(T_1) + E(T_2)$ via linearity, so it would be (because the expected value of a variable that takes distribution $Geom(p)$ is $1 / p$), $6/2 + 6/1 = 9$ rolls.

Is this reasoning/answer correct? I don't have too much intution for this kind of problem. If not please let me know where I went wrong!

Comment: @DavidK yes, given that we have seen *exactly* 4 distinct faces. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already observed 4 faces, since the probability to observe one of the two faces remaining is $p = 2/6 = 1/3$, the expected number dice throw before we observe one of the two faces remaining is $3$ and with the same reasoning. When we will have observed the fifth face, the probability to observe the last face at the next dice throw is $p = 1/6$ so the expected number of dice throw before we observe the sixth given we observed the five first faces is $6$. In conclusion the number of dice throw before we observe the two last faces is $6 + 3 = 9$. Was writing it on my way home, so if it doesn'make sense please tell me and I will rewrite it in a clearer manner.

Comment: yes, this makes sense! Above I somehow managed to write 6/2 + 6/1 = 4, when it is in fact 9. Thanks!